# Can't configure ADC using CCS THEIA -sys-config

Tags: microcontroller, texas-instruments, ti-ccstudio

Using a Ti MCU-MSPM0G1505. Using sys-config tool provided by Ti in CCS Theia .Trying to set ADC channel on pin 25.But not getting the option to set ADC on pin 25.Have attached the picture .Would any one be knowing what I am missing here?
This MCU has 17 channels of ADC and pin 25 is ADC_0.3.

DATASHEET:file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/ti/datasheet_1505.pdf

[image]

[image]

PIN 25 ANALOG FUNCTIONS:(LQFP64).....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.